# How can I read recent messages from my telegram account in python?

Tags: telethon

I am trying to read the recent messages from my telegram account to automate replies..

```
import configparser
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, utils

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read( "config.ini")

mySession = 'xyz'
myUserId = '@xyz'

async with TelegramClient(mySession, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    async for message in client.iter_messages(myUserId):
        print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

This Code asks for credentials and successfully logs me in..

```
Please enter your phone (or bot token): 9XXXXXXXXXXX
Please enter the code you received: 4XXXXX
Signed in successfully as SXXXXX
```

but..

```
myself = client.get_me()
print( myself.stringify())
```

returns..

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fddc5bc3f77b> in <module>
----> 1 print( myself.stringify())

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'stringify'
```

please help..

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Is it too obvious or not feasible? Please somenone answer me..

Comment: Come on guys.. nobody??

Answer (score 1):

For people that pass here : ".stringify()" doesn't exist in Python but exists in [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
You must use ".loads()" from the json library in Python, it is the equivalent.